# I have 4 way parallel i/p file, 6-way parallel i/p files.I want to write the data into 8-way multifile.How can you do this?

Tags: ab-initio

I have 4 way parallel i/p file, 6-way parallel i/p files.I want to write the data into 8-way multifile.How can you do this?

Answer (score 2):

You must **repartition** both input flows to 8-way using a Partition component.

- If the order doesn't matter and won't matter downstream, use
  Partition by Round Robin, which does what it sounds like: the records
  are redistributed evenly to the output flow's partitions.
- If the records are sorted or will be sorted downstream, use Partition
  by Key on both the 4-way and 6-way input flows, using the sort key. Partition by Key ensures all records with the same key will be on the same parallel partition, so they can be correctly sorted. If records are already sorted on the input flows, connect the two Partition by Key components to a Merge component using the same key, to combine them while maintaining order. If you will be sorting after combining the input flows, you can use a Gather component, since the order of individual records within each partition doesn't matter yet -- you are about to sort them in the 8-way flow.
- If the records will be processed downstream in groups, e.g. Rollup or Join, then you must partition by at least the first field of a multi-part key. This is more subtle, because a key may consist of multiple fields, e.g. {state;city}. You can partition by fewer fields before a Rollup, because that's sufficient to ensure all records with the same key are on the same partition. Partitioning by {state} ensures that all records with any unique {city;state} value will be on the same partition.